# To show "treat entered string text" to null & empty?

Tags: info-visualisation, information-architecture, data-tables, data-entry, data-collection

It's regarding the better representation of showing these option. I would like to explain in an elaborative way.

"A user can set data modification setting for further use. which might help other member users."

User might set few Execution Options:

**1. Treat empty text as null.

 2. Treat ______ text as null.**

Treat text ___________ as null string (checkbox)
Treat text ___________ as empty string (checkbox)

Note :_______ is entered value of user

I have tried few but not working for users

[image]

Comment: Does your userbase know what a Null value means?

Comment: Haivng Null and Empty next to each other is confusing, given how these terms are so similar but also so different in different contexts. I would need a little more information on its use case and implementation to help improve the solution.

Comment: From a user, perspective what is the difference in treating the entered text as null or empty?  I understand at code or database level it can be useful but why should a user select this option?

Comment: Who are your users and what is this for?

Comment: @mowwwalker User is Test Engineers/ Analyst. In short, the domain is testing domain.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the "Null" would be confusing for the most of people. I would used the "Empty" text.